# Extract data from templated derived class using virtual base class function

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

I have a `Device` object that can have 1 or more `State` objects. I do not want to limit what sort of *state* the `State` objects can describe so I've templated the `value` of the `State` objects. Since I want each `Device` to keep a collection of these `State` objects, I've derived them from a `GenericState` class.

I'd like to be able to interact with pointers to this `GenericState` class to read and write from the templated value, however templated virtual functions are not supported. My solution was to declare a purely virtual 'visiter' function in the base class that takes in a function with a `void*` argument. The templated derived class implements the virtual function and calls the passed in function with the value of the `State`. With this approach, I leave it up to the caller to choose what to do with the value (cast to a type, read, write, etc). Code snippets below.

My question is:

1. What are the issues with this sort of approach aside from it seeming 'hacky' and not the most readable?
2. Is there another, better approach to accomplish my end goal? I've looking into `std::variant` and `std::any` but `std::variant` doesn't seem as generic and `std::any` seems inappropriate. I've also considered static/dynamic casting but I'm not sure about their overhead.

My `Device` class that 'owns' a collection of states:

```
class Device {
    std::list<std::unique_ptr<GenericState>> states;
...
}
```

The `GenericState` and `State` classes themselves:

```
class GenericState {
public:
    std::string name;
    virtual ~GenericState() = default;
    virtual void visitValue(std::function<void (void*)> func) = 0;
protected:
    GenericState(std::string name): name(name) {}
};

template<typename T>
class State: public GenericState {
protected:
    T value;

public:
    State(const std::string& name, const T& value): GenericState(name), value(value) {}
    const std::string getName() {return name; }
    const T getValue() { return value; }

    // Calls the provided function with a reference to the value for read/write
    void visitValue(std::function<void (void*)> func) override {
        func(&value);
    }
};
```

An example of how a `GenericState` pointer can be used to read/write the `State`'s `value`:

```
State state = State(name, 5.0);
GenericState* genericState = &state;

// state.value = 5.0

double newVal = 0.2;
genericState->visitValue([&newVal](void* val){*(double *)val = newVal;});

// state.value = 0.2

double testVal = 0.0;
genericState->visitValue([&testVal](void* val){testVal = *(double *)val;});

// testVal = 0.2
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you plan to extend the list of states runtime (e.g. other process) or is the list known compile-time?

Comment: I plan to add devices at runtime. Once the devices are created, the states should be constant for each one.

Comment: It's not an issue to add devices; the only question is whether new State types are added (if they are, it's like loading a dll _in the middle of the program's run_ with completely new types). To me it looks it's not the case, but cmiiw.

Comment: Ah, I see the distinction. No, they should be possible to itemize at compile time so I think the approach you suggested with variant may make sense

Comment: If you're able to enumerate them compile-time, then it always makes sense to do so. I'd go to the extent that implement an enum for them and make the descendants simply specializations of a template over that enum (i.e., `StateEnum` and `template<StateEnum> class StateImpl { ... }`), because then you can generate most of the code (it's simply a compile-time loop over `StateEnum`).

Comment: With a variant, does it even make sense to template the State itself? Would it make more sense to just use the variant to store the value and get rid of the generic state altogether as State can now be stored in the container?

Comment: likely you've reinvented the variant pattern. That's a good thing :), it means your brain works like other programmers' brains. So yes, that's likely the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My - maybe opinionated - observation is that people overuse `virtual`, maybe because of how C++ is usually taught. `virtual` is very useful if you have to provide 30-years forward compatibility and module load without restart in a telco system; it's less useful when concrete types are known, esp. when you recompile the entire project after each change.

Here the caveat is, you'll lose all guarantees that type safety gives you. At each point where you call `visitValue()`, you'll have to specify the type of the value, because that `void*` hides it. The idea of type safety is, you should have type checks (thik of it as 'unit tests' in forms of type specifications) and these should fail if you miss it. Now, the key observation is, you will likely write `genericState->visitValue();` way more often than the number of `State`s. So you likely rather list the states once, e.g. in a `variant`.

As soon as you have it in a `variant`, you can simply `visit` it and have the concrete type - from that point, you have type safety. All this you win for listing all the states *once*.

```
using GenericStateVar = std::variant<State, State2, State3>;

GenericStateVar genericState(State(name, 5.0));

double newVal = 0.2;
std::visit([&](auto&& state) { // you might limit the capture here
    state.setValue(newVal); // consider making value public
}, genericState);

double testVal = 0.0;
std::visit([&](auto&& state) { // you might limit the capture here
    testVal = state.getValue(); // consider making value public
}, genericState);
```

It's so simple with `variant`, nothing else is needed. Also, `variant` tends to be somewhat faster that `virtual`, as the former is aware of all possible types (technically, it's a `switch` vs. function pointer).